# assigning a null value to another type fails to typecheck

Tags: typescript

playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AVAjMAvMA3gQwFzAM5gBOAlgHYDmwAPsKQK4A2DAvgFCujjRzwBMqGHLToBbAEYxC1YUzYdQAYwD2pAsAAeuJAKy56s9p2IAzYAAp1AOkyoUafQwCUGeZxDLVYYBC38061zcPPCUGGEsGJXIzCEcAbkC5YHYUlM52IA)

I wonder why the following fails to type-check:

```
type T1 = {a: string | null}

type T2 = {a: number | null}

const x: T1 = {a: null}

if (x.a === null) {
    const y: T2 = x
    console.log(y);
}
```

I can get around the problem by doing a:

```
const y: T2 = x as {a: null};
```

... but it's not clear to me why one has to do that. Why can't the Typescript compiler deduce that the value of `x.a` inside the block is null? Could it be that some asynchronously executed code might change the value of `x.a`? This doesn't seem right according to the mental model I have of how Javascript execution model works.

Comment: Because the type isn't narrowed to `{a: null}` by `x.a === null`, it's still `T1`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That much is clear, but why is it not narrowed inside the block?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57639697/3001761